# Run text as a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 2 columns . The first a serial and the 2nd is a query that stored as a text.
To more simple the question , at the end:  I wish to create a function which I will enter the number of the serial as a parameter and the function will return me the result of the query which  is found in the 2nd column.

I know I have to use the command 'execute'  from other questions I saw here on stack.

Even before the end result, I made this simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.try1()
 RETURNS TABLE(datery timestamp without time zone)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
stmt text;
BEGIN
         stmt :='SELECT b FROM chks where a=4';
          RETURN QUERY
  execute stmt ;
 END
$function$
```

The result of this query select b form chks where a=4 is:

'select now()::timestamp without time zone'

When I am running the function I get cast error which tells me the reutrn of th  fuction is varchar and not timestamp and if I change the return type to varchar I get as a result the query itself and not the result of the query.

What am I missing here?

In any case, is there a more simple way to do this? 
 I am asking this both for my simple function and for the function with the parameter I have mentioned before.

Comment: Do all stored queries return same number of columns of the same type?

Comment: @Igor - yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.try1(query_number numeric)
  RETURNS TABLE(datery timestamp without time zone)
AS $function$
DECLARE
stmt text;
BEGIN
  SELECT b INTO stmt 
    FROM chks 
   WHERE a=query_number;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE stmt;
END
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```